# IDebugControl::WaitForEvent works once then returns E_HANDLE

Tags: c++, winapi, com, dbgeng

I'm trying to make a small tool that makes use of the [Debugger Engine API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc265839.aspx), but I'm having very limited success.

I can get my [IDebugClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc265976.aspx) and [IDebugControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc266102.aspx) instances, and from there I am able to attach into an already running user process.  I then enter a main loop where I call [WaitForEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc266039.aspx), [OutputStackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc266034.aspx), [SetExecutionStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc266097.aspx)(`DEBUG_STATUS_GO`), and repeat.  In essence this will be a very crude sampling based profiler.

Good so far..

My loop runs for one full iteration, I can see a stack trace being displayed and then the target process going back into a running state.

The problem I have is that on my 2nd iteration the call to `WaitForEvent` returns `E_HANDLE` ("The handle is invalid").  I cannot see in the documentation why this error should be returned.  Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that I was compiling, linking, and running against an old version of the SDK.  Now that I've upgraded my SDK to the latest version (which I presume is the version that the online docs refer to) I get behaviour that is at least consistent with the docs.

I still have problems, but no longer this problem.